# Inverse trignometry finding the interval for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Derive the conditions on $x$ for which the equation holds:$$2\tan^{-1}x=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

How to find value of $x$ for which the equation holds?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025) instead of attaching an image.  Images are not searchable and cannot be read by a screen reader.  Also, please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) including showing your own attempts and discussing your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: sorry i am new here i have tried thinking alot but could not even proceed with a single step

Comment: Hm, your account says "member for $4$ years".

Comment: yes but i started asking questions recently

Answer (score 2):

If $2\tan^{-1}x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ your equation is equivalent to
$$
\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\sin(2\tan^{-1}x)
$$
But $\sin(2\tan^{-1}x)=2\sin(\tan^{-1}x)\cos(\tan^{-1}x)=\tan(\tan^{-1}x)
\cos^2(\tan^{-1}x)=\frac{\tan(\tan^{-1}x)}{1+\tan^2(\tan^{-1}x)}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$.
So your equality holds when $2\tan^{-1}x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, that is, when $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Is this a generalized technique??

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: can any question which asks to find an interval for x be done the same way

Comment: I don't think so. Each one requires its own analysis. There are general ideas like transforming into an equivalent equation, but nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ x\in \Bbb R$.

we know that $$1+x^2\ge 2x$$

and
$$1+x^2\ge -2x$$
So

$$-1\le \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\le 1$$

On the other hand, put

$$X=2\arctan(x)$$
with $-\pi<X<\pi$.

So,

$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\frac{2\tan(X/2)}{1+\tan^2(X/2)}=\sin(X)$$

and
$$\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})=X$$
only if $$X\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$$

which gives the condition
$$x\ge -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$2\tan^{-1}x = \sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Let $2\theta = 2\tan^{-1}x$

From the RHS,
$$x = \tan\theta$$
and
$$\tan2\theta = \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$

From the LHS,
$$\sin2\theta = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$
so
$$\cos2\theta = \pm \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$
since
$$(1+x^2)^2 = (1-x^2)^2 + (2x)^2$$
hence
$$\tan2\theta = \pm\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$

The signs of the LHS & RHS must agree, so $\cos2\theta \ge 0$. Hence $2\theta$ is in the 1st or 4th quadrants, i.e.,
$$-\frac\pi2 \le 2\theta \le \frac\pi2$$
$$-\frac\pi4 \le \theta \le \frac\pi4$$
$$\tan\frac{-\pi}4 \le \tan\theta \le \tan\frac\pi4$$
$$-1 \le x \le 1$$

Comment: how did we come to the conclusion that the cos2x >=0

Comment: @ParvezPatel The LHS (left hand side) of the original equation tells us that $$\tan2\theta = \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$ and the RHS tells us that $$\tan2\theta = \pm\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$ But the 2 sides must agree, so we have to reject the $-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ solution. If cos is positive, sin & tan have the same sign, and so we get the $+\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ solution. But if cos is negative, sin & tan have opposite signs, and we get the unwanted  $-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ solution. It may help to draw a simple diagram on the unit circle.